# How to get the number from the spinning wheel image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a image of spinning wheel. I am spinning that wheel after a interval of time. When it stops at a particular point, how do I get the value at that point?

Here is the code of the spinning wheel:

```
    setInterval(function () {
          var $r = $('.roulette').fortune(24);
     $r.spin();
    },30000);
   var $r = $('.roulette').fortune(24);

var clickHandler = function() {
  $('.spinner').off('click');
  $('.spinner span').hide();
  $r.spin().done(function(price) {
    $('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
    $('.spinner span').show();
  });
};
$('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
```

It spins after some interval and also on the click of a button. Now all I want is to get the value of the spinning wheel number, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: A spinning image ? What is `fortune(24)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I see what you want. I think you need to map the number to CSS rotate degrees first.

By using CSS below to rotate the image in HTML page

```
-ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(7deg);
```

What you need is to create a map JSON object {'0':'0','32':'5','15':'10','19':'15'...}
I am not sure the exact degree for each number but you can figure it out. Basically, just create a map like 'number':'degree'. Then your code can know how many degrees to rotate for what number, and vice versa.

Comment: http://www.goaonlinegame.com/wp-content/themes/casino/images/casino_logo.png this is the wheel. here are few numbers and I want these number to show whatever number come to a point